# I am not getting any output using v-for in my Vue project

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I have made an application where users can write comments on each other's profile page, but I have problems outputting the comments. I am not getting any errors in the console, but even though I am using v-for, the output I am getting on screen is {{ comment.from }} and {{ content.from }}. So I am not getting the actual data.
I can't seem to find the error.

The comments appear in my Firestore Database, and they also appear in the console log.

Here is my component for this part of my project.

```
<template>
    <div class="view-profile container">
        <div v-if="profile" class="card">
            <h2 class="deep-purple-text center"> {{ profile.alias }}'s Wall</h2>
            <ul class="comments collection">
        <li v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="index"> 
       <div class="deep-purple-text"> {‌{ comment.from }} </div> 
       <div class="grey-text text-darken-2"> {‌{ comment.content }} </div>
       </li>
            </ul>
            <form @submit.prevent="addComment">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="comment">Add Comment</label>
                    <input type="text" name="comment" v-model="newComment">
                    <p v-if="feedback" class="red-text center">{{ feedback }}</p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import db from '@/firebase/init'
import firebase from 'firebase'
export default {
    name: 'ViewProfile',
    data(){
        return{
            profile: null,
            newComment: null,
            feedback: null,
            user: null,
            comments: []
        }
    },
    created(){
        let ref = db.collection('users')

        ref.where('user_id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                this.user = doc.data(),
                this.user.id = doc.id
            })
        })

        ref.doc(this.$route.params.id).get()
        .then(user => {
            this.profile = user.data()
        })

        db.collection('comments').where('to', '==', this.$route.params.id)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
            if(change.type == 'added'){
                this.comments.unshift({
                    from: change.doc.data().from,
                    content: change.doc.data().content
             })
            }
          })
        })
    },
    methods: {
        addComment(){
            if(this.newComment){
                this.feedback = null
                db.collection('comments').add({
                    to: this.$route.params.id,
                    from: this.user.id,
                    content: this.newComment,
                    time: Date.now()
                }).then(() => {
                    this.newComment = null
                })
            } else {
                this.feedback = 'Please enter a comment'
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure your `comments` is populated ?

Comment: have you consoled your `comments`?

Comment: Yeah, I did. The comments appear in my Firestore database without any problems. I just can't get them to show up on the page itself. I tried console.log(this.comments). In the console I am getting `[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]` and INSIDE that I can see the comments just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this before, but I copied your code to make a snippet and noticed a red dot between the curly brackets like the picture below.

[image: Red dot in curly brackets]

I replaced them with {{ and it seemed to work. I've included the snippet below with and without the red dot version.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: 'ViewProfile',
  data() {
    return {
      profile: null,
      newComment: null,
      feedback: null,
      user: null,
      comments: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.profile = {
      alias: "Test"
    };
    this.comments = [{
      from: "Test",
      content: "Test"
    }];
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="view-profile container">
    <div v-if="profile" class="card">
      <h2 class="deep-purple-text center"> {{ profile.alias }}'s Wall</h2>
      <ul class="comments collection">
        <li v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="index">
          <div class="deep-purple-text"> {‌{ comment.from }} </div>
          <div class="grey-text text-darken-2"> {‌{ comment.content }}</div>

          <div class="deep-purple-text"> {{ comment.from }} </div>
          <div class="grey-text text-darken-2"> {{ comment.content }} </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That actually did the trick. I wonder why those dots were there? Anyway, it works now =)

Comment: I have no idea, it only seemed to be on the `comment.from` and `comment.content` brackets and not the `feedback` brackets. It's probably something to do with encoding.